# How to add custom price for custom line items added using commerce customizable products?

Tags: 7, commerce

I have created custom line items using "commerce customizable products" module by following the steps provided in this [screencast](http://commerceguys.com/blog/commerce-module-tuesday-commerce-customizable-products-screencast). I want to add custom price for each added custom line item and it would be great if i could add/specify the price while creating that line item. Is there any way to do it? If not I will be glad to help to do so, All I need is proper guidance. This is a well known issue and solving it would be an awesome addition to this module.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I havent found anything for line-items per say, but found this module that might work

https://drupal.org/project/commerce_pricing_attributes

Comment: Thank you but I have accomplished my task using "pricing rules".